# Filter a list of lists based on complex criteria

Tags: prolog

I have a list that might look like this:

A = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 4, 5, 6], [2, 6, 2, 4, 6, 7]] .

The first value of each sub list is important since it indicates the filtering predicate. So if the first value is `1` then everything after the 2'nd element plus `1` will be used for filtering. A few examples could be:

```
2, 6, 2, 4, 6, 7 : filter with 4, 5
1, 4, 5, 6       : filter with 6
```

Filtering is done by keeping all the sub lists that are contained in a different list:

```
M = [6, 3]
```

So if I have the `M` list above I need to keep the second list from the example, since I have the number 6, but I need to disregard the first list since I cant find 4 and 5 in `M`.

In order to do this I have created this function:

```
filter_list([], M, FilteredItems).
filter_list([H|T], M, FilteredItems) :-
    sublist(H, [Filt_pos|TFilt_pos], 0, 0),
    sublist(H, Keys, 3, 3 + (Filt_pos - 1)),
    (contains(Keys, M) -> append(FilteredItems, [H], FilteredStagesNew); !),
    filter_list(T, M, FilteredItemsNew).
```

The first `sublist/4` will take the first item of every item in the list I have to filter, wile the second is used to get the filtering items from each sub list, just as in the example above.

The helping functions are these:

```
contains([X], [X|_]).
contains([X], [Y|T]) :-
    X \== Y,
    contains([X], T).
contains([X,Y|T1], [X|T2]) :-
    contains([Y|T1], T2).
contains([X,Y|T1], [Z|T2]) :-
    X \== Z,
    contains([X,Y|T1], T2).

sublist(L1, L2, I, J):-
    sublist(L1, Temp, I, J, []),
    !,
    reverse(Temp, L2).
sublist([], L2, _I, _J, L2).
sublist(_L1, L2, I, J, L2):-
    I > J.
sublist(L1, L2, I, J, L2):-
    I < 0,
    sublist(L1, L2, 0, J, L2).
sublist([_L|Ls], L2, I, J, Acc):-
    I > 0,
    sublist(Ls, L2, I-1, J-1, Acc).
sublist([L|Ls], L2, I, J, Acc):-
    sublist(Ls, L2, I, J-1, [L|Acc]).
```

What happens when I run `filter_list` is that the filtering will be performed correctly, but then instead of moving to `filter_list([], M, FilteredItems).` and ending it just reverses (while I run it with a debugger). Why does the function above fail to filter the list as needed?

Comment: Your base case `filter_list([], M, FilteredItems).` is incorrect. You have two singleton variables which could be bound to anything and this clause would succeed.

Comment: @lurker yeah following the execution with the debugger it never reaches the base case. Is there something I could do to fix this? convlist I think is impossible to work on my case so I have to filter the list like this.

Comment: That would mean at some point your `append` is always failing, keeping it from making the recursive call.